# Upload a dotx template in sub site's Document Library's Content Type

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, file-upload, document-template

I have written a PowerShell script to upload a dotx template file in the document library for a custom site content type.Its working only at the root web level.But when I come to the sub web level's document libraries its not working.Do I need to write extra line of code to insert the dotx file in sub web level's document libraries and its associated content types also?

```
     Add-PsSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -
         ErrorAction:SilentlyContinue
          $siteurl = "https://dms1.prod.com/sites/ra"
          $web = Get-SPWeb $siteurl
           #Clear-Host
           $templateFolderPath = "D:\maddy\scripts\DotxTemplate"
           $filter = "*.dotx", "*.potx", "*.vst", "*.xltx"
           #$contentTypeFolders = ls $templateFolderPath | where 
           {$_.PsIsContainer}
           $contentTypeFolders=  $templateFolderPath
           Write-Host "content type folders is...."  $contentTypeFolders
           #pause
           $templateCount = (ls $templateFolderPath -Include $filter -
          Recurse | where {!$_.PsIsContainer}).Count
         Write-Host "template count"  $templateCount
           $path = $templateFolderPath  #$_.FullName    
              Write-Host   "path is....."  $path
            $foldername = $path  #$_.Name
          $i = 1
             #pause
       $fileMode = [System.IO.FileMode]::Open
          $fileStream = $null
      $cttypes = @("Contracts and Agreements","Memo")
       $contenttypeGUIDsArray = New-Object 
       System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection
        foreach ($cttype in $cttypes)
        {
         #$cttypeobject = $web.contenttypes[$cttype]
         $contentTypeName = $cttypeobject.Name
         $contentTypeID = $cttypeobject.ID
         $contenttypeGUIDsArray.Add($contentTypeID)
        }
     # TO BE DONe FOR IT 
     #$contenttypeGUIDsArray=@("")
       foreach($singlCTGUID in $contenttypeGUIDsArray) 
           { 
         Write-Host $singlCTGUID
            pause
       $spcontenttypeid = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPContentTypeId 
        $singlCTGUID
       #ls -Path $path | % {
          #Need to open a new spweb object, to "refresh" the current 
           content type object, to aviod database update conflict
         $web = Get-SPWeb $siteurl
         $spcontenttype = $web.ContentTypes[$spcontenttypeid]
          $fileFullname = 
          "D:\maddy\scripts\DotxTemplate\BlankTemplate.dotx"  
           #$_.FullName
           $filename = "BlankTemplate.dotx"  #"$_.Name
        #Write-Progress -PercentComplete (($i / $templateCount) * 100) -
          Activity "Uploading templates" -Status "$filename on content 
             type $($spcontenttype.Name)"
                 #$i++
           #try{
             #open the document template, as a filestream
             $fileStream = New-Object System.IO.FileStream($fileFullname, 
          "Open")
             #add the file (SPFile) to the content type resource folder 
         http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-
        us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spcontenttype.resourcefolder.aspx
             if($fileStream -ne  $null -and $spcontenttype -ne $null)
             {
             Write-Host "fielstream is not null ..inside fielstream not 
           null...block"
           $spcontenttype.ResourceFolder.Files.Add($filename, 
            $fileStream, $true)
            #$filestream = New-Object System.IO.FileStream($tofile, 
         "Create")
       #$binarywriter = New-Object System.IO.BinaryWriter($filestream)
          #$binarywriter.write($filebytes)
           #$binarywriter.Close()
            $fileStream.Close()
             #set the current document template file to be the document 
              tmeplate
             $spcontenttype.DocumentTemplate = $filename
             #update the content type
             $spcontenttype.Update($true)
             }
         }
         #finally             {                 $fileStream.Close()             
         }         }
```

I have referred the  blog :
 http://blog.andersdissing.com/2012/09/upload-content-type-template-through.html

Comment: Please post your script to give us a chance of seeing where it goes wrong

Comment: I have updated my code which is working with the document libraries within the root web.But this code is not working when I come to the sub web's document library's `New Document` in the ribbon

Comment: Any updates for this?I am unable to get the Document  Information Panel within the  document libraries that resides in sub webs.What am doing wrong? Any extra block of code is required for enabling uploading of dotx file within subwebs?